# Android - Out of bounds on a simple array

Tags: android

`tubeDataSplit` has multiple lines with 4 numbers seperated by `;` each row. `tubeDataSpliter` should split this 4 numbers and use it on `TubeData`.

**My problem is** that when `tubeDataSplit` is bigger than 4 the program crashes because `tubeDataSpliter` array is out of bounds. So I assume tubeDataSpliter is the size of the ; spacings.

How can I avoid this?

```
    String[] tubeDataSplit = tubeDataString.split("\\n");
    String[] tubeDataSpliter;

    for(int i=0; i<tubeDataSplit.length -1;i++) {


        tubeDataSpliter = tubeDataSplit[i].split(";");


        if (tubeDataSpliter[i] != null) {
            TubeData newTubeData = new TubeData(tubeDataSpliter[0], Float.parseFloat(tubeDataSpliter[1]), Float.parseFloat(tubeDataSpliter[2]), Float.parseFloat(tubeDataSpliter[3]));
            tubeDataArrayList.add(newTubeData);

        }

    }
```

Comment: nvm... I cant use `tubeDataSpliter[i]` it's `tubeDataSplit[i]`.

Comment: define `tubeDataSpliter` Array with same size of `tubeDataSplit` array

Comment: Check `tubeDataSpliter` size instead of `null` .

Answer (score 1):

Modify your if condition with below code:

```
 if (tubeDataSplitter != null && tubeDataSpliter.length >=4 ) {
            TubeData newTubeData = new TubeData(tubeDataSpliter[0], Float.parseFloat(tubeDataSpliter[1]), Float.parseFloat(tubeDataSpliter[2]), Float.parseFloat(tubeDataSpliter[3]));
            tubeDataArrayList.add(newTubeData);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0; i<tubeDataSplit .length(); i++){

    TubeData newTubeData = new TubeData();
    newTubeData.setTubeData(tubeDataSpliter[i]);
    tubeDataArrayList.add(newTubeData);
}
```

//In TubeData.class add string and generate getter and setter

```
private Strind tubeDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

`if (tubeDataSpliter[i] != null) {` is wrong.

When you have more than 4 lines than `i` becomes 4 or larger and `tubeDataSpliter[4]` is beyond the bounds of the array since it's length 4.

what you should do instead at that line is:

`if (tubeDataSpliter.length == 4) {`